# how to define the Truncated Polynomial?

Tags: ntru

In NTRUEncryption, I seen the **trucated polynimials**, but I cannot understand the trunacated polynomial calculation.
So, could tell me anyone How do we calculate the truncated polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "truncated polynomials" shouldn't really be used in relation to NTRU. A truncated polynomial is, strictly speaking, a polynomial with terms of order N or more discarded. NTRU instead uses polynomials mod $X^N-1$. So, for example, if $N=3$, then $x^2+1 * x^2+1$ = $x^4+2x^2+1$. Truncated this is simply $2x^2+1$. Reduced mod $X^3-1$, it's $2x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: thank you Mr.whyte , How we reduced by it?

Comment: See for example http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv.htm